# Single column in gnuplot-datafile is not accepted

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot some data in gnuplot (4.6.4 on Ubuntu), and I am running into a strange problem. The data I want to plot is this:

```
0.200002, 1.802499 , -0.019630 , -0.026596 , 1
0.200004, 1.782499 , -0.019846 , -0.024755 , 1
0.399999, 1.802497 , -0.011159 , -0.033270 , 1
1.050001, 0.494397 , 0.014552 , -0.005899 , 5
0.549997, 1.782498 , -0.005215 , -0.032049 , 1
1.099996, 1.782499 , 0.019503 , -0.022157 , 1
0.750003, 0.454500 , 0.001421 , 0.014648 , 6
0.850000, 0.414497 , 0.002620 , 0.031995 , 6
0.750002, 0.434501 , -0.000733 , 0.020472 , 6
0.999999, 0.434499 , 0.009604 , 0.024800 , 6
```

if it's saved as 'cleaned.csv' i have no problem to run

```
plot 'cleaned.csv' using 1
```

Which nicely plots the first colum. I can also plot the second or fourth row, but

```
plot 'cleaned.csv' using 3
```

results in

```
     warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                               ^
     x range is invalid
```

And I have no idea why this columns behaves differently.

Does someone else has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnuplot uses white spaces as separators for the data columns. Plotting the first and second column works fine, because for the first column the trailing comma is simply ignored, and the second row is separated by a white space. Now, the third column contains only commas, which gnuplot cannot parse to numbers, so that you effectively have no valid data points. Simply use

```
set datafile separator ','
```

or, since 4.6.6 and 5.0.0

```
set datafile separator comma
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks! The first command however does not work ("expected "<separator_char>"), but with the other syntax, I got the other colums.

Comment: Ok, I've just seen, that the first variant was introduced only in 4.6.6 and 5.0.